Skipping write to Firestore if Anonymous user logic
So this use case is pretty straightforward: I have a couple of sign-in providers activated in my Firebase web app as you can see in the picture.
Mostly my sign-in and sign-up logic is handled in the front-end with vanilla JS, I have 5 different scripts, one for each SSO provider.
Now why I did like this is another topic, but I fetch and store different types of user data depending on which social media provider they signed in with. This is also because the APIs returns different parameters.
Anyhow, everything works flawless when a user follows the on boarding that its setup to have in my web app when they sign-up, but if they bypass it and goes straight to sign-in page and authenticate with a SSO provider from there, the data in Firestore data is not stored properly, instead, my Cloud Functions I have created to prevent update/write for Anonymous users is triggered and that node.js script is triggered and overriding the front-end instead.
Now I want to handle this from the front-end because I am storing data in localStorage that I need to use (like i18n language selection etc) among other things.
My question is this: How do I keep a Cloud Function that only prevents Anonymous users data to be written in Firestore? There seem to not be enough to only have a simple function that checks the providers length and return null. So any idea would be appreciated!

"There seem to not be enough to only have a simple function that checks the providers length and return null." Why not?  Can you show what you tried for this approach that didn't work?

It would be helpful to include a couple of examples of requests to your Cloud Function, one where the request should be blocked (along with what happens to that data), and one where the request should be permitted (along with how that data is handled). RE: "the data in Firestore data is not stored properly" - what is not stored? are you referring to stuff sent back by the original auth provider like the external user ID, usernames, profile pictures, and access tokens?

Hi, I added  the CF for you to inspect.
@samthecodingman what I mean is, it seems like I have to do a '  if (!userSnapshot.exists) ' logic in my CF because if I dont, the front-end code that sets the doc is not triggered with all those data fields I have specified.

So to be clear: The goal here is to regardless of how the user authenticates, these are the fields that are suppose to be stored in Firestore          uid: user.uid,
email: user.email,
displayName: user.displayName,
phone: user.phoneNumber,
picture: profilePicture,
lang: localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage'),
The purpose of the CF is to prevent Anonymous users that visits my web app to be stored to the DB.

@FrankvanPuffelen

@samthecodingman

Isn't this check in your code working if (user.isAnonymous) {? If not, consider checking if the user has any providerData. iirc that array is empty for anonymous users (as there is no provider to provide such information).

I mean the issue here is that I check both in front end and in back end if user is anonymeos, I am suspecting this is what causing the issue. It's like in Firebase console it creates 2 rows of uIDs, one anonymeos and one with the identifier the user just signed in with.
And to answer your question Frank yes that code snippet works, but that causes then no user to be writen in Firestore, even though it's a "non-anonymous one". The problem also is that I have 2 CF, one with the new Cloud Run 1:st gen and one without, I am considering deleting them and do the auth logic in client side.

@AndreKoroshKordasti Based on what you've provided here, I think the Cloud Function is causing confusion instead of helping solve the root cause. Can you provide the source for the "sign in" screen that is causing your "sign up" logic to be skipped? What I suspect is happening is that the logic on that screen is not checking signInResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser, not handling it appropriately, or is navigating away before your sign up logic completes thanks to an onAuthStateChanged hook.

In your current logic, you are calling a signInWith method, then after it succeeds, you are creating the required Firestore document. But you also don't appear to be doing this in all places where a sign in is possible in your application.
Care should be taken to always handle the result of the Auth#signInWith and User#linkWith calls across your application in a consistent way. To help with this, we are going to create a handleUserCredential callback that processes the result of these sign in and link requests with the same logic. If the handled credential represents a new user, or there is new profile information available because a new account is linked, we want to update the user's data in their Firestore document.
// Note: using legacy/compat (namespaced) syntax to match question. Use modern (modular) syntax where possible in new projects.

const handleUserCredential = async (userCredential /* firebase.auth.UserCredential */) => {
  // extract useful information from userCredential
  const credentialProviderId = userCredential.credential.providerId;
  const user = userCredential.user;
  const providerUserInfo = user.providerData
    .find(userInfo => userInfo.providerId ===  credentialProviderId);
  const userDocRef = firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid);

  // define helper function for async errors.
  const rethrowLinkedError = (err) => {
    // attach credential for when an error handler may need it
    try {
      err.userCredential = userCredential;
    } catch (attachError) {
      console.error("Could not attach credential to thrown error.", attachError);
    }
    throw err;
  }

  // treat as new user if isNewUser flag is true, or when that
  // user's data does not exist in Firestore
  const isNewUser = userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
    || !((await userDocRef.get().catch(rethrowLinkedError)).exists);

  if (!isNewUser && userCredential.operationType !== 'link') {
    // user is not new, missing data, nor is linking an account.
    // return early while passing userCredential to next handler
    return userCredential;
  }

  // if here, the signed in user is new, their Firestore data is
  // missing, or a new sign in method was just linked to an
  // existing account that may need its profile updated.

  // scaffold out the base document data from the User object
  // we'll override these below as needed
  const userDocData = {
     uid: user.uid,
     email: user.email,
     displayName: user.displayName,
     phone: user.phoneNumber,
     picture: user.photoURL, // recommend using photoURL for consistency
  }

  const langPreference = localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage');
  if (langPreference || isNewUser) {
    // only update language for new users or when a preference is set.
    // otherwise, leave setting as-is on Firestore
    userDocData.lang = langPreference;
  }

  // override user data based on the newly added provider
  switch (credentialProviderId) {
    case 'google.com': // GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      if (!userDocData.picture && providerUserInfo.photoURL) {
        // use Google's provided photo when one was not already set.
        // the "if not already set" check can be removed as desired.
        
        // Remove the size parameter
        userDocData.picture = providerUserInfo.photoURL.replace(/=\s*s\d+-c/, '');
      }
      break;
    case 'facebook.com':
      // ...
      break;
    // ... other handlers
  }

  await userDocRef
    .set(userDocData, { merge: true })
    .catch(rethrowLinkedError);

  // consider also adding:
  // await user.updateProfile({
  //   displayName: userDocData.displayName,
  //   photoURL: userDocData.picture
  // })
  //   .catch(rethrowLinkedError);

  return userCredential;
}

Note: In the above code, I removed lang from the base user data document. This was so that when a preference does not exist in local storage, you don't inadvertently remove their preference stored in Firestore.

The above function can then be chained to the result of the Auth#signInWith* or User#linkWith* methods.
// Note: using legacy/compat (namespaced) syntax to match question. Use modern (modular) syntax where possible in new projects.

firebase.auth()
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(handleUserCredential) // <-- handles the result and passes it on
  .then((result) => {
    // if here, user is now signed in, and their Firestore document was updated as needed.
    
    setTimeout(() => window.location.href = "../pages/home.html", 1000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    switch (err.code || err.message) {
      case "auth/user-disabled": // example Authentication error handling
        // TODO: handle this error
        break;
      case "permission-denied": // example Firestore error handling
        // TODO: handle this error
        break;
      default:
        if (err.code && err.code.startsWith("auth/")) {
          // handle general auth error
        } else if (err.code) {
          // handle other error, likely, but not guaranteed, to be related to Firestore
        } else {
          // handle other unexpected error
        }
    }
  })

// Note: using legacy/compat (namespaced) syntax to match question. Use modern (modular) syntax where possible in new projects.

const auth = firebase.auth();

auth.currentUser
  .linkWithPopup(provider)
  .catch(err => {
    // if here, the link operation failed. Determine what to do with
    // the credential that could not be linked.
    if (err.code === "auth/credential-already-in-use") {
      // sign in with the other account instead? cancel? error?
      return auth.signInWithCredential(err.credential);
    }
    throw err; // rethrow other errors
  })
  .then(handleUserCredential) // <-- handles the result and passes it on
  .then((result) => {
    // if here, user is now signed in, and their Firestore document
    // was updated as needed.
    
    // if result.operationType === 'link', the accounts were linked.
    // if result.operationType === 'signIn', the link failed and the user
    // was instead signed in directly with that account.
    
    setTimeout(() => window.location.href = "../pages/home.html", 1000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // TODO: Handle errors as above.
  })

Potential errors:

firebase.auth.AuthError
firebase.auth.Error
firebase.firestore.FirestoreError (codes listed at FirestoreErrorCode)
Any other error. Firebase-related errors are more common, but these will appear for errors in handleUserCredential or handlers in the promise chain.

